# 4k Monitor Cable for 3840 x 2160 Resolution at 60Hz

Tags: display, macbook-pro, cable, displayport, 4k-resolution

I just purchased a Dell 4K monitor (P2715Q) and I am looking for an appropriate cable to use with my MacBook Pro. I've read that certified DisplayPort cables are best to use with a 4K monitor like this one. Are there any DisplayPort cables out there that support 3840 x 2160 resolution at 60Hz?

Comment: One thing that *isn't* covered by my answer is whether your MBP's video card can handle 4k out. That's not a function of the cable tho

Answer (score 0):

The cable that comes with your monitor should work fine. Depending on what interface you use with your MBP, it ought to be a simple matter of using mini displayport on your MBP and the full sized DP in on the monitor or vice versa.

If you're *buying* a cable, the folks who maintain the displayport specifications [suggest *any* cable that meets displayport port specifications](http://www.displayport.org/cables/how-to-choose-a-displayport-cable-and-not-get-a-bad-one/)  would work fine with 2160p60 , and they have a list of certified cables. Just pick one from a reputable manufacturer and make sure one end's mini dp for your MBP and the other end's either a full or mini dp (since your monitor has both for input, and another full sized one for daisy chaining).

Its also worth noting that thunderbolt ports are backwards compatible and work as displayports.